# Consumir una imagen desde una API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Tengo las siguientes variables que he creado para mostrar los datos en pantalla de una API de Marvel.

```
 var fila = $('<tr></tr>');
                var columna_id = $('<th></th>').text(personaje.id);
                var columna_avatar = $('<td></td>').html('<img src=" '+personaje.thumbnail+' "/>');
                var columna_first_name = $('<td></td>').text(personaje.name);
                var columna_desciption = $('<td></td>').text(personaje.description);
```

Necesito poder mostrar la imagen que esta en un objeto con esta ruta:

thumbnail:
extension: "jpg"
path: "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784"

Comment: Voy a resumir un poco el problema que tienes, no puedes usar cualquier recurso de la red si no es publico y ademas no tienes acceso a el debido a algo llamado CORS, en tu caso no se esta bloqueando el recurso por CORS sino por .htaccess que es algo que tu no puedes controlar, puesto que no creo que seas tu el que haya creado la API... (solo el propietario de la API puede dar acceso a ciertos dominios), por ejemplo con una API KEY, pero a no ser de que la API acepte una API KEY que tu tengas, no tendras acceso al archivo, conclusión: deberás usar otra API publica o conseguir acceso.

Comment: La API si deja consumir sus datos y las imágenes sin problemas, yo no se como llamarlas correctamente, pero no requiere de permisos.

Comment: Menos mal, entonces tu si tienes acceso a la API, en mi caso al ir directamente a la URL propuesta me da el siguiente error: Forbidden, lo cuál significa que no tengo acceso. sin embargo ahora que se sabe que tu tienes acceso al recurso, deberas proveer un poco mas de información... por ejemplo, cuál es la estructura de la variable personaje?, la cuál no provees, nos serviria mucho mirar como es mas o menos para orientarte en ese aspecto, porque si enrealidad deseas colocarlo dentro de la etiqueta img que provees en el código entonces es mucho mas sencillo todo.

Comment: @SebaLagos, considera cerrar esta pregunta y que parece ser un "duplicado" de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362911/llamar-a-imagen-con-data-tables)