# Llamar a imagen con data tables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

Necesito poder insertar el campo imagen de una respuesta json desde la api de marvel.
estoy utilizando el plugin de jquery data tables.

Url de la imagen:

```
imagen_personaje.attr('src', personaje.thumbnail.path + '/landscape_small.' + personaje.thumbnail.extension)
```

DataTables:

```
  $('#tabla').dataTable({
    ajax: {
        cache: true,
        url: `https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?&ts=${ts}&apikey=${publicKey}&hash=${hash}`,
        dataSrc: 'data.results'
    },
    columns: [{
        "data": "id"
    }, {
        "data": "ImagePath",
        "render": function (data) {
        return '<img src="' + thumbnail.path +'/>';
        }
    }, {
        "data": "name"
    }, {
        "data": "description"
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data), los parámetros que recibe la función son:

- `data`: el valor para la celda (*si fue configurado la propiedad `columns.data`*)
- `type`: la cadena que indica que tipo de acción se realizo para obtener el valor (*filter, order, display*)
- `row`: el objeto completo asignado a la fila

Entonces, teniendo esto en cuenta, la solución podría ser:

```
  ...
}, {
  "render": function(data, type, row) {
    return `<img width="100" src="${row.thumbnail.path + '.' + row.thumbnail.extension}"/>`;
  }
}, {
  ...
```